# Security holes in XAMPP for Windows?

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I need to install a MySql server on my Windows machine to run a local database. does anyone know if this thing poses a vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...XAMPP is not meant for production use but only for developers in a development environment. XAMPP is configured is to be as open as possible and to allow the web developer anything he/she wants. For development environments this is great but in a production environment it could be fatal. "

Here a list of missing security in XAMPP:

```
* The MySQL administrator (root) has no password.
* The MySQL daemon is accessible via network.
* phpMyAdmin is accessible via network.
* The XAMPP demopage is accessible via network.
* The default users of Mercury and FileZilla are known.
```

Read this for more:
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1221

Answer (score 1):

when you first install MySQL it only allows local users to access the DB, so I don't see any vulnerabilities.